# Python: Rescale time-series in pandas by non-integer scale-factor

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation, resampling

I have no idea if this is feasible in Pandas. I thought `df.resample` may do the work but no. Here's my objective:

I have a time-series in a `DataFrame`, `df` that looks like this:

```
            return
12:30:00 -0.000202
12:30:01 -0.000257
12:30:02 -0.000230
12:30:03 -0.000229
12:30:04 -0.000253
...
12:59:49  0.001491
12:59:50  0.001523
12:59:51  0.001503
12:59:52  0.001484
12:59:53  0.001513
12:59:54  0.001523
12:59:55  0.001527
12:59:56  0.001545
12:59:57  0.001532
12:59:58  0.001535
12:59:59  0.001566
13:00:00  0.001605
```

This is the plot:

[image]

Now you can you see that the time goes from `12:30:00 to 13:00:00`. I want to re-scale or stretch the this time-series to have observations from `12:30:00 to 14:15:00`. Hence I need to have 3.5 more entries in my original time-series... so 3.5 times more duplicate entries for each observation in my time-series. If it was only 3 time mores, then I would transform my data into array and use `np.reshape()` and then re-assign a time index but this won't work in this particular case. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to resample, with interpolation for non-integer time points. You'll need some signal-processing or statistical interpolation library. You'll need to decide/ experiment with which interpolating function you pick.

Comment: Ya I see what you mean in the interpolation. The issue is that I don't know how to take a time-series that is spread over 30 minutes and spread over one-hour and 45 minute with `nan` in between numbers. Then the use of interpolation afterwards becomes easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the datetime to unix epoch, multiply by your scale factor and then convert back (epoch calculation using [How to get unix timestamp from numpy.datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865458/how-to-get-unix-timestamp-from-numpy-datetime64))

```
df['epoch'] = df.index.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9     
start_epoch = df.epoch.iloc[0]
df['epochdelta']= df['epoch'] - start_epoch
df['newindex'] = pd.to_datetime((df.epochdelta * 3.5 + start_epoch),unit='s')
```

Comment: cool suggestion! Thanks. I will try tomorrow when I get back to the office and get back to you.

Comment: It's a lot faster to calculate epoch as

"df['epoch'] = df.index.astype(np.int64)// 10 ** 9"

Comment: thanks @Miro yes this is much nicer, i've edited my answer!