# Error when converting numpy.datetime64 to int

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert np.datetime64 to int via int(np.datetime64(...)). Surprisingly sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't depending on how was datetime created:

```
a = np.datetime64('2017-09-26T15:20:11.546205184')
int(a)
a = np.datetime64('2017-09-26')
int(a)
```

will results int:

```
1506439211546205184
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

Is there a difference in how those dates are stored internally by numpy and then causing error when converting to int?

Comment: this error actually is not specific to dates; if your date/time string specifies any ***precision less than nanoseconds***, you must ***also specify a [unit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units)*** for `int(...)` to work. I think this behavior ensures that the conversion to a serial date/time is unambiguous - if the unit of the input datetime is e.g. *seconds*, the result is *seconds* since the Unix epoch and so on.

Comment: *However,* using `.astype(np.int64)` will work in any case, and return Unix time in the precision you specified. E.g. `np.datetime64('2017-09-26T15:20:11.546').astype(np.int64)` will give you milliseconds since the epoch etc.

Comment: Related: [How to get unix timestamp from numpy.datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11865458/10197418)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The difference is whether it include time values, such as hours, minutes, and seconds.**

When you try to convert datetime (or `np.datetime64`) to `int` (or `np.int64`), the value will be [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Epoch_Times), which is a value of seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (utc).

(See epoch time calculator: https://www.epochconverter.com/)

However, if you try to convert "2017-09-26" to int, it is hard to calculate how many seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 because the value does not include hour, minutes, seconds information and timezone information.

To make it convertable, you have to add time information, as follows:

```py
a = np.datetime64('2017-09-26T00:00:00.000000000')
print(int(a)) # 1506384000000000000 --> This is an epoch time for 2017-09-26 00:00:00

a = np.datetime64('2017-09-26','us').astype(np.int64) # not int, use np.int64
print(a) # 1506384000000000 -> This is also a epoch time for 2017-09-26 00:00:00
```

In addition, please use `astype(np.int64)` instead of `astype(int)` to convert it to exact epoch time when your value is saved as `datetime64`. If you use `int`, this will return the number of days from 1970-01-01.

```py
a = np.datetime64('2017-09-26T15:20:11.546205184').astype(int)
print(a) # 1072585728 -> not an epoch time, but days from 1970-01-01

a = np.datetime64('2017-09-26T15:20:11.546205184').astype(np.int64)
print(a) # 1506439211546205184 -> a correct epoch time of 2017-09-26 15:20:11 with miliseconds
```

- edited with consideration of @FObersteiner 's comment, Thanks!

Comment: "*it is impossible to calculate*" - well it is possible, but you have to make assumptions about the time and the time zone (which a bare date does not have). Interestingly, `np.datetime64('2017-09-26').astype(np.int64)` gives you the number of days since the Unix epoch 

Comment: @FObersteiner Oh, thank you for the comment. I edited the some wording as you commented. I did not know that it was the number of days. I thought the information was lost by converting `int64` to `int32`. Thank you again :)

Comment: you can check with `np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00') + np.timedelta64(np.datetime64('2017-09-26').astype(np.int64), 'D')` - and I think it is safe to assume that the unit of a date must be 'days', also considering that numpy's datetime assumes UTC by default and doesn't do weird local time stuff like native Python datetime.

Comment: @FObersteiner Nice tips!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a = np.datetime64('2017-09-26','us').astype(np.int64)
```